# Pointer and char in struct

Tags: c++

How to read the second letter in char with a pointer? I can read the whole message "carp" and first letter 'c' but I have no idea how to read second letter... Here is my example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct list {

        char name[20];
        int length;
    };

    list first ={
        "carp",
        6,
    };

    list *p = &first;
    cout << p->name << endl; // "carp"
    cout << *p->name << endl; // "c"
    p = p + 1;
    cout << *p->name << endl; // Not working...How to read a?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cout << *(p->name+1) << endl; ` should do the trick and remove the `p = p +1`

Comment: `p` is a pointer to `list` not to `list::name`. Incrementing it would move `p` up to the next `list` in an array of `list` objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Incrementing `p` with `p++` or `p = p+1` moves you to the next instance of `struct list`, which is not what you want (and it's not even there).

Instead, you want to move to the second letter of `name`, which can be done in several ways:

- Use index on the name - `cout << p->name[1] << endl;`
- Make a pointer to `p->name` and increment it, i.e. `char *np = p->name; np++; cout << *np`
- Use pointer arithmetic instead of indexing, i.e. `cout << *(p->name+1) << endl;`

Comment: @MartinBonner You are right, that's yet another way to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use *index* on `name` to access any character:

`p->name[1]` // gives 'a'

`p->name[2]` // gives 'r'

Note that arrays begin with an index of 0. So `p->name[0]` would give `'c'`.

`p + 1` actually increments `p`, which is a pointer to `list`. This essentially moves to the next instance of `list`, which is not even initialized in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Use the array [subscript operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_subscript_operator) with an index of `1`:

```
p->name[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output the second character using pointers without the subscript operator then you can just write

```
cout << *( p->name + 1 ) << endl;
```

It is the same as

```
cout << p->name[1] << endl;
```

Or you can introduce an intermediate pointer. For example

```
for ( const char *q = p->name; *q != '\0'; ++q )
{
    cout << *q;
}
cout << endl;
```